# aligning GitHub and Twitter buttons in React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have been racking my brains over these two buttons. For the life of me I can't seem to align them properly.

You can seen them here https://mrpbennett.com

I normally do this by using flexbox and aligning centre. It seems the twitter button is a bit weird. I tried to remove the margin on the bottom from the iframe the twitter button sits in.

```
<div className={homeStyles.followBtns}>
                    <GitHubButton
                        href="https://github.com/mrpbennett"
                        data-color-scheme="no-preference: light; light: light; dark: dark;"
                        data-size="large"
                        aria-label="Follow @mrpbennett on GitHub"
                    >
                        Follow
                    </GitHubButton>

                    <TwitterFollowButton
                        screenName={'mrpbennett'}
                        options={{
                            size: 'large',
                            showScreenName: 'false',
                            showCount: 'false',
                        }}
                    />
                </div>
```

```css
.follow-btns {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-bottom: 1rem;

    :first-child {
        margin-right: 0.5rem;
    }
}

iframe {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

This is how I have tried. But the Twitter button just doesn't seem to want to align....any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
follow-btns : {
       display : 'flex';
       margin-bottom: 1rem;
       align-items: 'baseline';
    }
```

everything else the same as you have written.

Comment: didn't work im afraid it's like the twitter button has a mysterious margin

Comment: just add `align-items : 'baseline';` into the css you have written, i tried this and it's working on my screen.

Comment: can you provide a screen shot possibly? Because it's not working on mine...https://imgur.com/PDHPd2m

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/YwdiAnl is this what you are pursuing for ?

Comment: yes!! how did you do that??? Ok it works in Chrome but NOT Safari

Comment: I have only used `align-items : 'baseline';` maybe you should try to set 0 margins for twitter button

Comment: the iframe that it sits in has no margins it's odd for sure

Comment: can you make a sandbox or jsfiddle, I can try there

Comment: not quite sure how to do it with jsFiddle and React...you can fork the repo if you want https://github.com/mrpbennett/gatsby-me